# How can insert Data one Linked Server to Other Linked Server.

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
set @sql='DECLARE @SourcePKTable TABLE (rowno int identity(1,1),myOldPK INT)
IF EXISTS(SELECT Company_ID FROM [LServer2].[CMS].[dbo].[tbl_MasterCompany] WHERE Is_Sync IS NULL)
BEGIN 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [CMS_WA].[dbo].[tbl_MasterCompany] ON
INSERT INTO  [LServer1].[CMS_WA].[dbo].[tbl_MasterCompany]
([Company_ID],[CompanyName],[ContactNumber],[Mobile],[Fax],[Email],[Website],[Logo],[Address],[Description]
,[Is_Deleted],[Is_Active],[Is_Used],[CreationDate],[Created_By],[Updated_By],[LastUpdation])

SELECT [Company_ID],[CompanyName],[ContactNumber],[Mobile],[Fax],[Email],[Website],[Logo],[Address],[Description],[Is_Deleted]
,[Is_Active],[Is_Used],[CreationDate],[Created_By],[Updated_By],[LastUpdation]
FROM [LServer2].[CMS].[dbo].[tbl_MasterCompany]  
WHERE Is_Sync IS NULL 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [CMS_WA].[dbo].[tbl_MasterCompany] OFF

END
ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT Company_ID FROM [LServer2].[CMS].[dbo].[tbl_MasterCompany] WHERE Is_Sync =0)
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO @SourcePKTable
SELECT Company_ID
FROM [LServer2].[CMS].[dbo].[tbl_MasterCompany]
WHERE Is_Sync =0


UPDATE [LServer1].[CMS_WA].[dbo].[tbl_MasterCompany]
   SET [CompanyName] = Webtbl.CompanyName
      ,[ContactNumber] = Webtbl.ContactNumber
      ,[Mobile] = Webtbl.Mobile
      ,[Fax] = Webtbl.Fax
      ,[Email] = Webtbl.Email
      ,[Website] = Webtbl.Website
      ,[Logo] = Webtbl.Logo
      ,[Address] = Webtbl.Address
      ,[Description] = Webtbl.Description
      ,[Is_Deleted] = Webtbl.Is_Deleted
      ,[Is_Active] = Webtbl.Is_Active
      ,[Is_Used] = Webtbl.Is_Used
      ,[CreationDate] = Webtbl.CreationDate
      ,[Created_By] = Webtbl.Created_By
      ,[Updated_By] = Webtbl.Updated_By
      ,[LastUpdation] = Webtbl.LastUpdation
FROM  [LServer2].[CMS].[dbo].[tbl_MasterCompany] Webtbl INNER JOIN 
[LServer1].[CMS_WA].[dbo].[tbl_MasterCompany] Wintbl 
ON Webtbl.Company_ID=Wintbl.Company_ID
WHERE Webtbl.Company_ID IN (SELECT myOldPK FROM @SourcePKTable) 

    DELETE FROM @SourcePKTable
END '


 EXEC [LServer1].[CMS_WA].dbo.sp_executesql @sql
```

when execute given query :

```
Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 52
Could not find server 'LServer1' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.
```

****LServer1 is my local server

Comment: We really need some details of your setup before we can help. Which version of SQL Server? Have you added the linked server?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why you're using this, if `LServer1` is the local server:

```
INSERT INTO  [LServer1].[CMS_WA].[dbo].[tbl_MasterCompany]
```

Why not just:

```
INSERT INTO  [CMS_WA].[dbo].[tbl_MasterCompany]
```

?

If you really want to use 4-part naming for the local server (not sure why), you should validate that `SELECT @@SERVERNAME;` returns the value that you expect. It could be a named instance or it may have been renamed. If it is a named instance then you will have to use `[LServer1\InstanceName]`; if it has been renamed then you will need to use [`sp_dropserver` / `sp_addserver` to make sure SQL Server is aware of the new name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx):

```
EXEC sp_dropserver N'old name';
GO
EXEC sp_addserver N'LServer1', 'LOCAL';
```

(And again, adjusting accordingly if it should be a named instance.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of red flags raised around what you're trying to do here, but I think you've given just enough information to make some guesses as to what is going on.

When you say `LServer1` is your local server, I suspect you mean that `LServer1` is the host to which you are connected and from where you intend to run your query.  Otherwise, the error message you are getting absolutely indicates you've simply forgotten to set up at least the first of the linked servers you are referencing on the server to which you are connected.  If it is not a mere oversight, then what you are attempting to do is reference the `LServer1` linked server from the context of `LServer1` itself.  Even if you are on a third server altogether, you will at least need to remove the `LServer1` references from at least your dynamic SQL block.  Consider your execute command:

```
EXECUTE [LServer1].[CMS_WA].[dbo].[sp_executesql] @statement = @sql;
```

In running this command, you are telling the engine to use the server object `LServer1` to execute an `sp_executesql` command; a batch defined by `@sql`.  If `LServer1` is a server object available to the server to which you are connected ( not to be confused with the server you are connected to itself ), the batch as defined by `@sql` would then be executed in that server object's context ( effectively, the batch occurs on `LServer1` as opposed to the server to which your session originates ).  However, the batch itself also includes references to `LServer1`, meaning that `LServer1` as you have defined it would itself need a server object ( linked server ) available also named `LServer1` to complete.  Based on the query you are trying to run, I feel it is safe to assume that `LServer1` is not intended to be a self-referencing construct.

Here is the first major issue with what you are trying to run in the context of `LServer1`:

```
    INSERT  INTO [LServer1].[CMS_WA].[dbo].[tbl_MasterCompany] ( 
        [Company_ID], [CompanyName], [ContactNumber], [Mobile],
        [Fax], [Email], [Website], [Logo], [Address], [Description],
        [Is_Deleted], [Is_Active], [Is_Used], [CreationDate],
        [Created_By], [Updated_By], [LastUpdation] )
    SELECT  [Company_ID], [CompanyName], [ContactNumber], [Mobile],
            [Fax], [Email], [Website], [Logo], [Address], [Description],
            [Is_Deleted], [Is_Active], [Is_Used], [CreationDate],
            [Created_By], [Updated_By], [LastUpdation]
    FROM    [LServer2].[CMS].[dbo].[tbl_MasterCompany]
    WHERE   Is_Sync IS NULL;
```

At this point, you are already executing in the context of `LServer1`, so the self-reference here is likely incorrect.  Alternatively, since I feel it's likely you are trying to execute the batch on a server which you are not connected to ( and I'm still assuming you are connected to `LServer1` ), chances are you should probably change your `sp_executesql` reference to `LServer2` in your original `EXECUTE` and remove the `LServer2` references from the `@sql` definition.

```
        UPDATE  [LServer1].[CMS_WA].[dbo].[tbl_MasterCompany]
        SET     [CompanyName] = Webtbl.CompanyName,
                [ContactNumber] = Webtbl.ContactNumber,
                [Mobile] = Webtbl.Mobile,
                [Fax] = Webtbl.Fax,
                [Email] = Webtbl.Email,
                [Website] = Webtbl.Website,
                [Logo] = Webtbl.Logo,
                [Address] = Webtbl.Address,
                [Description] = Webtbl.Description,
                [Is_Deleted] = Webtbl.Is_Deleted,
                [Is_Active] = Webtbl.Is_Active,
                [Is_Used] = Webtbl.Is_Used,
                [CreationDate] = Webtbl.CreationDate,
                [Created_By] = Webtbl.Created_By,
                [Updated_By] = Webtbl.Updated_By,
                [LastUpdation] = Webtbl.LastUpdation
        FROM    [LServer2].[CMS].[dbo].[tbl_MasterCompany] Webtbl
        INNER JOIN [LServer1].[CMS_WA].[dbo].[tbl_MasterCompany] Wintbl
                ON Webtbl.Company_ID = Wintbl.Company_ID
        WHERE   Webtbl.Company_ID IN (  SELECT   myOldPK
                                        FROM     @SourcePKTable );
```

This is possibly going to do things you are not expecting as well.  If your local session is `LServer1` and you accordingly remove the `LServer1` references to get this to work at all, the `LServer2` select is likely going to pull every single row for the `Webtbl` across the network and into local memory ( then spill into tempdb ), before will be able to apply the `WHERE` clause using a table variable which has been created in the local batch on `LServer1`.  Keep an eye out for `OLEDB` and `NETWORK_IO` wait types when running this query, it probably won't take long for you to see it.  In the opposite context, where you had intended to run the query on `LServer2`, you *may* get away with a more optimal I/O path, but keep an eye on it anyway.